# Gradle upload a single archive to multiple repositories

Tags: maven, gradle

My team currently has two Maven repositories, with Gradle being used to upload artifacts to either one or the other (depending on what project we are working on). One of these repos is private to within our company, whilst the other is a repo that is accessible to us and to a third party company.

We've now reached a point where if we make a change to a project, we want the newly created artifact to be uploaded to both repos instead of just one. However we found that writing something such as the code below does not work as expected:

```groovy
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        repository(url: "http://repo1/releases")
        snapshotRepository(url: "http://repo1/snapshot")
        repository(url: "http://repo2/releases")
        snapshotRepository(url: "http://repo2/snapshot")
    }
}
```

For some reason, Gradle only uploads the archive to second repository in the list (i.e. repo2).
I realise that whilst we could just edit our Gradle file to *download* from multiple repositories, I was just wondering if it is actually possible to *upload* an artifact to multiple as we cannot seem to get this to work.

Comment: If it helps, we're using Gradle version 1.3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One `Upload` task can only publish to one repository. You can, however, declare another `Upload` task. Something like:

```
task uploadExternal(type: Upload) {
    configuration = configurations.archives
    uploadDescriptor = true
    repositories { ... }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Was this was a Gradle design choice? Just wondering. =)

Comment: I ended up using your solution, which is using multiple upload task. However I'm still curious about this statement "One Upload task can only publish to one repository". Is this true? 1. The name imply its plural 2. I looked up at the Upload.class and it has List of Repository 3. In the Gradle docs itself "In Maven you can define repositories and optionally snapshot repositories. If no snapshot repository is defined, releases and snapshots are both deployed to the repository element. Otherwise snapshots are deployed to the snapshotRepository element.". No mention about single repository.